# .htaccess RedirectMatch not working with Question Mark Sign

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect one URL to another. From URL:

```
http://domain.com/?acc=cfcd208495d565ef66e7dff9f98764da&bannerid=8&pid=5
```

To:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php/blog/target
```

I am using:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)cfcd208495d565ef66e7dff9f98764da.* http://www.domain.com/index.php/blog/target
```

it is not working if from URL I just remove ? before `acc` it start working. if anyone has any idea please let me know.

Comment: `RedirectMatch` does not allow you to specify a query string. You might try using `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` instead. This might be helpful: [Apache .htaccess query string redirects](http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/).